# load image into writeablebitmap

Tags: c#, silverlight, writeablebitmap

So Im trying trying to load an image into a WriteableBitmap but I'm getting a NullReferenceException. Can't figure out why because I think this used to work before

`BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images/Car.jpg", Urikind.Relative));`
    `WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(b);`

thats it. I have the car image as a resource in my project. It works fine as I can create a Image control and set its source to the BitmapImage and display it.
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As seen from other SO questions, it seems that the reason you get the null reference exception is that [BitmapImage.CreateOptions Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.createoptions%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) default value is `BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation`. You can set it to `BitmapCreateOptions.None` and create `WriteableBitmap` after image loaded:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("somepath",UriKind.Relative));
img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
img.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
   {
       WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)s);
   };
```

Using that code, the `WritableBitmap` will wait until the `BitmapImage` is loaded, and then it will be able to be assigned to the `WritableBitmap`.